# Android SDK Manager Proxy Settings in LINUX

Tags: android, ubuntu, proxy, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to install the Android SDK, in Ubuntu, behind my work firewall and am getting 'failed to connect to dl-ssl.google.com' messages. This is a known problem but every solution I see involves proxy settings and selecting the 'force http' option. It appears that this is straightforward in windows, however I'd like to know how to do the same in LINUX. I can set the eclipse proxy settings but I don't think this gets used by the android sdk manager. Is there a config file somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if it helped you, so this question does not show up as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution was to setup a local proxy to perform authentication and create the file ~/.android/androidtool.cfg to redirect android to the local proxy as follows.

```
### Settings for Android Tool
#Tue Jun 12 01:34:55 PDT 2012
http.proxyPort=3128
sdkman.monitor.density=108
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
sdkman.show.update.only=true
sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
sdkman.force.http=true
sdkman.show.updateonly=true
```

This file may already exist with entries such as

```
http.proxyPort=
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1\:3128
```

For me, this did not work until I changed it to the form shown above:

```
http.proxyPort=3128
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This fixed it for me - the proxy port was the issue.

Comment: My proxy requires authentication as well, but just supplying `http.proxyPort` and `http.proxyHost` did the trick; the Android tooling asked for credentials to get through that proxy.

Answer (score 6):

Just to help someone out there.

I was able to use SDK Manager with Proxy settings with following procedure

1. Goto Shell (Ctrl+Alt+T for ubuntu)
2. Run "android" from the sdk\tools directory. (example /mySDKDir/tools/android)
3. This would launch the SDK Manager. On the Main menu, goto Tools -> Options to setup the proxy settings.
4. Select the relevant packages and download/install. SDK Manager would use the proxy settings specified.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you run this command:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://my_proxy:port/
```

in a shell before running `android` or `eclipse`, the SDK tools should honour that.

If you want it to take effect permanently account-wide, add the above line to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: it doesn't. Environment: debian, android sdk build date 2013.10.30, x64.

Comment: I can confirm that, for me, using `HTTP_PROXY` (all caps) rather than `http_proxy` _did_ work. But it's 'weird', I needed to `export HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@myproxy.com:8080/`, `export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@myproxy.com:8080/`, and run this command _once_ `sdkmanager --proxy=http --proxy_host=myproxy.com --proxy_port=8080 --list`. After doing this, I didn't need the env vars any longer, nor any of the proxy options to to `sdkmanager`. (I can only assume that the proxy settings got cached somewhere[?])

Answer (score 1):

I was able to edit the ~/.android/androidtool.cfg with my actual proxy information, save the fact that I had to use the IP Address of my Proxy (Worked), rather than it's hostname (Did Not Work). Seems the Android SDK Management in Linux is unable to resolve names.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the settings of android androidtool.cfg Windows to Linux file and it worked perfectly